# How can I fix broken delay in pygame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, game-development, runner

I have been making a  basic runner game. This is only the first part. I added delay, so that when the character jumps up, it doesn't go back down automatically, but it works kind of wrong. This is the code:

```
import pygame

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 550))
run = True

positionx = 100
positiony = 300

def update_screen():
  screen.fill((0, 100, 255)) #backgorund
  player = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 255, 255), (positionx, positiony, 50, 80))
  ground = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 255, 0), (0, 380, 600, 550))

def jump():
  global positiony
  positiony = positiony - 60
  update_screen()
  
  pygame.time.delay(1000)
  
  positiony = positiony + 60
  update_screen()

while run:
  update_screen(0)

  for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
      pygame.quit
      
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == 32:
      jump()

  pygame.display.update()
```

The jump message displays, only after the 1 second delay. If I change the jump() function to something like, for example:

```
def jump():
  global positiony
  positiony = positiony - 60
  update_screen()
  
  pygame.time.delay(1000)
  
  positiony = positiony - 60
  update_screen()
```

Then the character will react only after the delay, even if the first update was before

Is this a glitch?

Comment: No, this isn't a glitch.  `delay()` pauses the entire program for the given amount of time.  Nothing else can happen while the program is paused.  Messages aren't shown, characters don't move.

Answer (score -1):

here's an example of jump in pygame

```py
import pygame
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 550))
pygame.display.set_caption("Jump Game")
# position of player
positionx = 100
positiony = 300
# geometry of player
width = 30
height = 40
# states and variables
isjump = False
v = 10
m = 1
run = True
def update_screen():
  screen.fill((0, 100, 255))
  player = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 255, 255), (positionx, positiony, 50, 80))
  ground = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 255, 0), (0, 380, 600, 550))

def jump():
  global positiony,v,m,isjump
  F =(1 / 2)*m*(v**2)
  positiony-= F
  v = v-1
  if v<0:
    m =-1
  if v ==-11:
    isjump = False
    v = 10
    m = 1

while run:
  update_screen()

  for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
      run=False
  keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
  if isjump == False:
    if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
      isjump = True

  pygame.display.update()
  if isjump :
    jump()
  pygame.time.delay(10)
  pygame.display.update()
pygame.quit()
```

Also as said in the comments,this isn't a bug in pygame.

- Also `delay()` will `pause the program for an amount of time`,since the program is single threaded it may sometime be not responsive
- but since you are making a runner game the player only moves in the `y` direction and the platforms makes the illusion of running.So delaying while jumping probably pause the entire program,
- for the current use case a jump program can be written to solve this,The above program works on the basis of  `F =(1 / 2)*m*(v**2)`(equation from GeeksForGeeks website).

Comment: I was not the one who downvoted, but you don't really explain what you changed and how that change works, your code has variables with meaningless names, the code relies heavily on 'global` (bad! bad! bad!) and the indentation is still 2 levels and not 4 as PEP-8 strongly suggests.

Comment: Thanks @cool-guy! It sure does help with the basics of jumping, but have you noticed that right before the character is coming down, you are able to double-jump?